# Carregar a pagina com uma tabela montada, e depois redesenha-la com uma informação diferente

Tags: php

Bom dia a todos!
Senhores, tenho a seguinte necessidade: Preciso carregar uma pagina do meu site com informações referentes ao dia atual, e caso o usuário queira, ele tem a opção de escolher a data que quer realizar a pesquisa.
O que eu não estou conseguindo é, criar a tabela com a data escolhida pelo usuário, em cima da tabela que já existe e foi carregada junto com a página.
Alguém sabe como resolver?
Agradeço desde já!

Comment: se puder adicionar mais detalhes as chances de sua pergunta ser respondida é maior

Comment: você quer fazer isso assíncrono? verifica a documentação do $.ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/